# Times series analysis vs. machine learning?

Tags: time-series, machine-learning

Just a general question. If you have time series data, when is it better to use time series techniques (aka, ARCH, GARCH, etc) over machine/statistical learning techniques (KNN, regression)? If there is a similar question that exists on crossvalidated, please point me towards it--looked and couldn't find one.

Comment: Relevant: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/13937/which-machine-learning-algorithms-can-be-used-for-time-series-forecasts

Answer (score 11):

Typical machine learning methods assume that your data is independent and identically distributed, which isn't true for time series data.  Therefore they are at a disadvantage compared to time series techniques, in terms of accuracy.  For examples of this, see the previous questions [Ordering of time series for machine learning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3337/ordering-of-time-series-for-machine-learning?rq=1) and [Random forest is overfitting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/45731/random-forest-is-overfitting).

Comment: thanks for your response. To further your point, it seems that machine learning is more concerned on finding relationships in the data, whereas time series analysis is more concerned with correctly identifying the causes of the data--i.e. how stochastic factors are affecting it. Do you agree with this?

Comment: No, I would not agree with that summary.

Answer (score 5):

As @Tom Minka pointed out most ML techniques assume iid inputs. There are a few solutions though:

1. One can use all the past time series samples within the system 'Memory' as one feature vector, ie: x=[x(t-1),x(t-2),...x(t-M)]. However, this has 2 issues: 1) depending on your binning, you may have a huge feature vector 2- some methods require features within the feature vector to be independent, which isn't the case here.
2. There exist many ML techniques which are specifically designed for such time-series data, for example Hidden Markov Models, which have been used very successfully for seizure detection, speech processing, etc...
3. Finally, an approach I have taken is to use 'feature extraction' techniques to convert a dynamic regression problem (which has the element of time) into a static one. For example, the Principal Dynamics Mode (PDM) approach maps the input past feature vector ([x(t-1),x(t-2),...x(t-M)]) onto a static one ([v(1),v(2),..v(L)]) by convolving the past with a system-specific linear filterbank (the PDMs),  see Marmarelis, 2004 book or Marmarelis, Vasilis Z. "Modeling methodology for nonlinear physiological systems." Annals of biomedical engineering 25.2 (1997): 239-251...

Answer (score 4):

Francis Diebold recently posted ["ML and Metrics VI: A Key Difference Between ML and TS Econometrics"](http://fxdiebold.blogspot.be/2017/03/machine-learning-and-econometrics-vi.html) on his blog. I am providing a shortened version of it, so all credit goes to him. (Emphasis in bold is mine.)

> [S]tatistical machine learning (ML) and time series econometrics (TS)
>   have lots in common. But there's also an interesting difference: **ML's
>   emphasis on flexible nonparametric modeling of conditional-mean
>   nonlinearity doesn't play a big role in TS.** <...>
>
> [T]here's very
>   little evidence of important conditional-mean nonlinearity in the
>   covariance-stationary (de-trended, de-seasonalized) dynamics of most
>   economic time series. <...> Indeed I can think of only one type of
>   conditional-mean nonlinearity that has emerged as repeatedly important
>   for (at least some) economic time series: Hamilton-style
>   Markov-switching dynamics.
>
> [Of course there's a non-linear elephant in the room:  Engle-style
>   GARCH-type dynamics. They're tremendously important in financial
>   econometrics, and sometimes also in macro-econometrics, but they're
>   about conditional variances, not conditional means.]
>
> So there are basically only two important non-linear models in TS, and
>   only one of them speaks to conditional-mean dynamics. And crucially,
>   they're both very tightly parametric, closely tailored to specialized
>   features of economic and financial data.

Thus the conclusion is:

> **ML emphasizes approximating non-linear conditional-mean functions in
>   highly-flexible non-parametric fashion. That turns out to be doubly
>   unnecessary in TS: There's just not much conditional-mean
>   non-linearity to worry about, and when there occasionally is, it's
>   typically of a highly-specialized nature best approximated in
>   highly-specialized (tightly-parametric) fashion.**

I recommend reading the whole original post [here](http://fxdiebold.blogspot.be/2017/03/machine-learning-and-econometrics-vi.html).

Comment: +1. I highly agree with this answer. Typical ML methods are characterised by nonparametric modelling and have very relaxed assumptions while ARMA models are "tightly-parametric".

Answer (score 1):

As said in other answers, ML methods required the i.i.d assumption and therefore are unsuitable to be used naively for time series. Not-naive ways have been suggested by DankMasterDan.

There is a further option, which is to use supervised predictors inside time-series forecasting. A good overview is found in the [Sktime documentation: Forecasting, supervised regression, and pitfalls in confusing the two](https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/examples/01a_forecasting_sklearn.html).